# How to save a file securely in Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am building an application where I need to generate PDF and save it on disk. However the file can only be access on authorization i.e. only loggedin user let's say with user role Admin can access the file and no one else can access those file.

Please guide me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Spring-Security..

I'm no expert in Spring-Security, but what I would do initially is have an endpoint with @PathVariable, so the variable would be the key id for the search for the file on disk, but each user can only access their own key, and such validation rule has to be done in the backend.

for example:

```
/doc/215425245354
```

spring-security will validate the access to `/doc/**` and the key you implement the validation if it matches the user's file or not, in order to not let him access a file of another user.

I hope I was able to give you some direction. :)